# Wrap the innerHtml in span if its not already

Tags: jquery, html

I'm not sure how to go about this, so here's my dilemma :

I have my about div with regular text inside. However after some js spans are added within it. But I'd like to wrap the existing text in a span tag. How would I go about wrapping spans to the text that isnt in a span already?

[Made a fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/PXTuD/4/).

```
<div class="about">
    This text isn't wrapped in an html tag
    <span>But this is</span>
</div>
```

how do i wrap the regular text into a span tag via jquery?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use jQuery's `.contents` to get text nodes and then wrap them if they are text node children of the checked node.

```
$(".about").contents().filter(function () {
    return this.nodeType === 3 && this.parentNode == $(".about").get(0);
}).wrap("<span>");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/PXTuD/6/

Comment: This just wraps the whole content of the `<div>` including the text and the `<span>` in another `<span>`

Comment: @LeeMeador it doesn't wrap the other span

Comment: It does in your fiddle on my version of Chrome. At least according to my debugger.

Comment: Version 26.0.1410.64. It says it is up-to-date today.

Comment: @LeeMeador unable to reproduce

Comment: FireFox shows it this way: `<div class="about"><span>
    This text isn't wrapped in an html tag
    </span><span>But this is</span><span>
</span></div>` (hard to read in a comment but its right)

Comment: Tried again in Chrome. Perhaps I was halucinating. It looks like the FireFox now.

Comment: Ya, had to delete mine.  This looks like the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

This would do it by putting spans around the whole thing:

```
$("div").html("<span>" + $("div").html() + "</span>");
```